# How do I know the bounds of my mmaped allocation?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, mmap

I am creating an anonymous mapping using mmap, of 12 bytes (small I know)

```
p = mmap(NULL,
        12,
        PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE,
        -1,
        0);
```

Then I want to verify if I can write beyond this 12 bytes

```
p=p+13;
strcpy(p,str);
printf("String at p is %s\n", ((char *)p));
```

Sure enough I can read and write to this region. I try to move across ~5 pages by incrementing my pointer by 20,000. The page size on my system is 4096. I found this out using sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE). I can still read and write to the pointer

Whats going on? Am I doing something wrong or are there some glibc limits that I haven't reached yet?

Edit: To verify, I would like my code to fail, beyond crossing some limit and I am unable to realize where that limit is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small increments, you're just seeing an artifact of the fact that virtual memory is organized by pages. The page size is the smallest increment of memory that can be assigned to a process.

For large increments, you're probably just running into a page that was allocated for some other purpose, such as the heap, stack, or the mapping of some other file.

Comment: shouldn't the large increments fail, in that case? specifically I am trying to understand when I can fail out of reading or writing beyond some bound. In my case, the bound seems to not be reached even with 5 pages, when all i asked for is 12 bytes!

Comment: Suppose your heap uses addresses 10,000 through 50,000, and mmap assigns a block at location 6,000. When you add 20,000 to the mmap address, that's 26,000, which is in the middle of the heap. You can't depend on it ever failing, there's no reason why the system can't assign adjacent address pages for different purposes, and you'll just overflow from one to the next.

Comment: Interesting. So its upto me to exercise good behavior or is there sometime that glibc is going to complain?

Comment: It's up to you. Or use a language that makes it hard to access memory directly (Perl, PHP, Python, Lisp, Ruby).

Comment: Well this is really an implementation of malloc itself which I am trying to design.

Comment: If you're designing a new malloc implementation, you have to keep track of the bounds of the heap you're managing. You can't depend on the system to send you a signal when you step out of bounds.

Comment: You can explicitly allocate a page and remove all permissions from it to ensure there is an invalid page after your valid page(s), this is what "fence post" allocation debuggers (for example, see `efence`) do.

Comment: But if the application increments a pointer by enough to jump over the guard page, it won't notice this. But it's useful for catching applications that are stepping through by small intervals.

Comment: Guys, with a bit of testing I realized that glibc did warn me when I jumped ahead of my allocated space. First, I increased the initial mmap to 512 Kbytes. Then I tried jumping ahead of 512 Kbytes and sure enough with a reasonable range (512*1050 for instance) gave me a segmentation fault. Although Bamar, you are correct that this is very flaky and the bounds check must be maintained by me.

Comment: PT that is a very interesting perspective too. Never thought of that :)